# What is the meaning of カックン in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, katakana, manga, onomatopoeia

Context: before a boxing match begins, a boxer named Kamishiro says this referring to his opponent:

> 勘だけど　あの**カックン**野郎…　刺せるヤツだ

What is the meaning of カックン? The opponent was a thug in the past and he his obsessed with precisely cut hair, but none of these details seems to be relevant. The only similar expression I could find is [膝カックン](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E8%86%9D%E3%82%AB%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%83%B3), but I don't think it could fit the context.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwdDd.jpg) you can see the page before and the page with the sentence in question. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this カックン means 角刈り{かくがり}(crew cut). The thug's hair is 角刈り. The speaker said カックン野郎 as a funny way of saying 角刈り野郎.

This is 角刈り.

[image]

Comment: +1 but it should be noted that カックン is not a common way of referring to this hairstyle. It's probably his own wording.

Comment: @Yuuichi thank you for your answer! Is this hair style usually associated with thugs like him?

Comment: @Marco No. The hair style is often associated with macho man.